# sizeof(int*) in 32-bit compatibility mode

Tags: c, malloc, x86-64, backwards-compatibility

Running the following on Linux x86-64 compiled with `gcc -m32`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main() {
    int a = 4;
    int* ptr = &a;

    printf("int* is %d bits in size\n", CHAR_BIT * sizeof(ptr));
    return 0;
}
```

results in

```
int* is 32 bits in size
```

Why I convinced myself it ought to be 64 bits (prior to executing): since it is running on a 64-bit computer in order to address the memory we need 64 bits. Since &a is the address of where value 4 is stored it should be 64 bits. The compiler could implement a trick by having the same offset for all pointers since it is running in the compatibility mode, but it couldn't guarantee congruent data after calling malloc multiple times. This is wrong. Why?

Comment: The size of a `char` (aka byte)  is `CHAR_BIT`, which is not necessarily 8.

Comment: The Linux kernel can run 32bits program if it's configured to do so, and I suppose that then it does a special mapping for the memory virtual space that the program will see. So a pointer in a 32bit ELF will be 32bits wide even if it's running on a 64bit OS because the OS is responsible to do the translation. I speak about Linux but I am sure that it's appliable to other OS's

Comment: " it is running on a 64-bit computer" - means nothing if the code itself is compiled as 32bit, which yours is.

Comment: IA32e CPU have a *Compatibility mode* which is equivalent to the usual environment of a 32 bits only CPU. Pointers are 32 bit in this mode.

Comment: What would be the point of using `-m32` if you got a 64-bit executable anyway? ;-)

Comment: `-m32` compiles a 32-bit program that can run on any 32-bit x86 computer. It's not legacy mode on 64-bit architectures. As it's a 32-bit program, obviously the pointer size would be 32 bits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the hardware level, your typical x86-64 processor has a 32-bits compatibility mode, where it behaves like a x86 processor. That means memory is addressed using 4 bytes, hence your pointer is 32 bits.

On the software level, the 64 bits kernel allows 32 bits processes to be run in this compatibility mode.

This is how 'old' 32 bits programs can run on 64 bits machines.

The compiler, particularly with the -m32 flag, writes code for x86 addressing, so that's why `int*` is also 32 bits.

Comment: Say calling malloc twice got me `a` referring to `36 5b 6c e9` and `b` referring to `f0 21 e5 17` (2 random 4-byte memory address). What are common ways of dereferencing `a` or `b` on a 64-machine, to actually get the values referenced by `a` or `b` (in compatibility mode)? I am struggling with the concept of converting 4 byte addresses into 8 byte addresses.

Comment: To get if they reference the same value: `a == b`. For the rest, each process has its own virtual address space; there's no way for your application to say where in physical memory (and if it is in memory) the objects are. Their physical location can change during the course of the program. This is true before 64 vs 32 bits even comes into consideration.

Comment: @TomArtiomFiodorov: `mov eax,[address]` (or similar), exactly as on a 32-bit machine. The point is that a user-mode process lives in a virtual address space anyway (that is mapped to the physical memory through the MMU), both on a "real" 32 bit and on a 64 bit machine in "32 bit compatibility" mode. The difference between the two cases lies in how the MMU is programmed by the OS, but everything is (mostly) transparent to a 32 bit process.

Comment: @TomArtiomFiodorov The process is running in a virtual address space. The address will be converted from virtual to physical by the MMU, the program has no knowledge of the real physical address under the hood, whether the address bus is 32 or 64 bits...

Comment: Whilst I understand now that the size of the pointer has to be 32-bit due to 32-bits instruction set (eax register is 32 bits) the source of my confusion has now moved to how MMU does it. I now know where to look.

Comment: Turned my comments into an answer, and deleted them.

Answer (score 1):

Modern CPUs have a [memory management unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit), it makes possible that every program has its own address space. You could even have two different programs using the same addresses. This unit is also what detects segmentation faults (access violations). With this, the addresses a program uses are not the same as the addresses on the address bus that connects the CPU and the peripherials including RAM, so it's no problem for the OS to assign 32-bit addresses to a program.

Answer (score 0):

An x86-64 machine running a 64bit OS runs 32bit processes in "compat" mode, which is different from "legacy" mode. In compat mode, user-space (i.e. the 32bit program's point of view) works the same as on a system in legacy mode (32bit everything).

However, the kernel is still 64bits, and can map the compat-mode process's virtual address space anywhere in physical address space. (so two different 32b processes can each be using 4GB of RAM.)  IDK if the page tables for a compat process need to be different from 64bit processes. I found http://wiki.osdev.org/Setting_Up_Long_Mode, which has some stuff but doesn't answer that question.

In compat mode, system calls switch the CPU to 64b long mode, and returns from system calls switch back.  Kernel functions that take a user-space pointer as an argument need simple wrappers to do whatever is necessary to get the appropriate address for use from kernel-space.

The high level answer is that there's hardware support for everything compat mode needs to be just as fast as legacy mode (32bit kernel).

IIRC, 32bit virtual addresses get zero-extended to 64bit by the MMU hardware, so the kernel just sets up the page tables accordingly.

If you use an address-size override prefix in 64bit code, the 32-bit address formed from the 32bit registers involved will be zero-extended.  (There's an x32 ABI for code that doesn't need more than 4GB of RAM, and would benefit from smaller pointers, but still wants the performance benefit of more registers, and having them be 64b.)